# Generalized Hough Transform for shape detection

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform

I want to use Generalized Hough Transform using OpenCv, but i didn't found any documentation.

How can i apply it ?
What are the opencv routines for that ?

Comment: OpenCV doesn't have a Generalized Hough Transform implementation--you're on your own. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation by Jguillon on github, which is OpenCV implementation of the generalized Hough transform as described in [Ballard1981].

The link is https://github.com/jguillon/generalized-hough-tranform.  I build it with Visual Studio 2010 and it works.